# MathJax does not render inside an JS object

Tags: render, mathjax

I'm writing a quiz in JS and my problem is that I need a lot of formulas, that's why I use MathJax, it works perfectly in HTML.

I'm trying to implement MathJax inside an object for questions and answers but it doesn't render.

This is the MathJax script:

```
 <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">   MathJax.Hub.Config({
     extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],
     jax: ["input/TeX","output/HTML-CSS"],
     tex2jax: {inlineMath: [["$","$"],["\\(","\\)"]]}   }); 
 </script>  
 <script type="text/javascript"   
 src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js"> 
</script>
```

Sorry if this question is repetitve or stupid, I just can't find the right solution.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you may have to force re-rendering, I had a similar problem. I would need more specifics though to help you. You may want to take a look at the queues mathjax uses: http://mathjax.readthedocs.org/en/latest/typeset.html

Comment: how do you re-render?

Comment: Here is the following code: http://jsfiddle.net/f3Lbgzoc/ , I'm trying to modify the JSON variable "sample" with formulas inside as questions and answers, the purpose of it, is to create an mathematical quiz for 7-8th grade

Comment: you should be able to get the element by id ( as you are doing ) and have it rendered via `MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub,Element);` if I remember correctly. There is more detail on the page I linked, and there may be other methods offered by mathjax.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips.